TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests in Maven configuration
I have a maven project with system and unit tests. I want to run JUnit plugin tests in headless mode. When I run the JUnit plugin tests from Eclipse using the option Run As -> JUnit Plugin Tests, it works fine. However, when I try to run them from the command line, I encounter the following error:
org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:160)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverSafely(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:134)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:110)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.test.EclipseTestRunner.runTests(EclipseTestRunner.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.test.EclipseTestRunner.run(EclipseTestRunner.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.test.UITestApplication.lambda$0(UITestApplication.java:103)

Eclipse Version: 4.24
Test Project and Plugin Projects: Exported JAR files are placed in the Eclipse dropins folder.
pom.xml Configuration:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <version>${revision}</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <properties>
    <tycho.version>4.0.6</tycho.version>
    <sonar.exclusions>**/src-gen/**</sonar.exclusions>
    <env.ui.test>-Xms512m -Xmx2048m</env.ui.test>
    <revision>0.9.8-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <tycho.compiler.target>1.8</tycho.compiler.target>
    <tycho.compiler.source>1.8</tycho.compiler.source>
  </properties>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>eclipse</id>
      <url>https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-12</url>
      <layout>p2</layout>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.69</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>eu.agno3.jcifs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcifs-ng</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.lingala.zip4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>zip4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.1</version>
    </dependency>     
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.11.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.4.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.12.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.5.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.3.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
          <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
          <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${tycho.version}</version>
          <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
          <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
          <artifactId>tycho-p2-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
          <artifactId>tycho-versions-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
          <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <!--
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
          <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
          <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
          <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho.extras</groupId>
          <artifactId>tycho-pack200a-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho.extras</groupId>
          <artifactId>tycho-pack200b-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${tycho.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.cbi.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>eclipse-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.1.7</version>
        </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>        
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
      </plugin>
     </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-toolchains-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>toolchain</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <toolchains>
                    <jdk>
                      <version>1.8</version>
                    </jdk>
                </toolchains>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <optimize>false</optimize>
          <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-p2-repository-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-p2-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-p2-metadata</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>p2-metadata</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-versions-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin> 
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <environments>
            <environment>
              <os>win32</os>
              <ws>win32</ws>
              <arch>x86_64</arch>
            </environment>
          </environments>
          <target>
            <artifact>
              <groupId>com.com.example</groupId>
              <artifactId>com.com.example.myproject.targetplatform</artifactId>
              <version>${revision}</version>
            </artifact>
          </target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>sign</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>sign</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>verify</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <keystore>${project.parent.basedir}/myproject.resources/Server.Dev/BuildFiles/cacerts</keystore>
          <alias>ppmsign</alias>
          <storepass>{8JkjoygA2awHsZMTWiDsr3i8jMkNMPLG6j0T3BABtIw=}</storepass>
          <keypass>{uoAZa7ob2PAHunGgsbG4BpzSLXw62o+I3X/l1dKOa2Ja3VsK3j/wzXEhYaBVu++2}</keypass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>        
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <modules>
    <module>myproject.plugin</module>
    <module>myproject.test</module>
    <module>myproject.feature</module>
    <module>myproject.p2</module>
    <module>myproject.product</module>
    <module>myproject.targetplatform</module>
  </modules>
</project>

with org.junit.jupiter-5.9.2 version added there was a conflict in dependency tree
 \- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:5.11.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:5.11.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.14.12:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.14.12:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.3:test
[INFO]    \- (org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.10.2:test - omitted for conflict with 5.9.2)

I have changed to org.junit.jupiter-5.10.2, there are no conflicts anymore but it still fails to discover tests.
